# React typescript redux reducer type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I want to use 'useSelector' to select proper state of rootStore, but can't get state properly. The reason is auth reducer of RootState gives me type never.

How can I access any values from the user object properly?

My store looks like this :

```
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default { store, persistor};

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

My auth reducer looks like this :

```
import {
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_REQUEST,
  LoginDispatchTypes,
} from "../actions/types";
import { User } from "../types/index";

interface initialStateI {
  token: string;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
  user?: User;
  error: string;
}

const initialState = {
  token: "",
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: false,
  error: "",
};
export default function (
  state: initialStateI = initialState,
  action: LoginDispatchTypes
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        user: action.payload.user,
        token: action.payload.access_token,
        error: null,
      };
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        token: null,
        user: null,
        error: action.payload.message,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My action looks like this :

```
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
export const LOGIN_FAIL = "LOGIN_FAIL";
export const LOGIN_REQUEST = "LOGIN_REQUEST";
import { User } from "../types/index";

export interface LoginSuccess {
  type: typeof LOGIN_SUCCESS;
  payload: {
    expires_in: number;
    user: User;
    access_token: string;
    token_type: string;
  };
}

export interface LoginFail {
  type: typeof LOGIN_FAIL;
  payload: {
    message: string;
  };
}

export interface LoginRequest {
  type: typeof LOGIN_REQUEST;
}

export type LoginDispatchTypes = LoginRequest | LoginFail | LoginSuccess;
```

This is how i try to display the user details on my view :

```
  const { user : currentUser} = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.auth);
```

Also the type user is in this format:

```
export interface User {
  email: string;
  author_id: number;
}
```

Any advice or recommendations/useful links on how to access data from state will be highly appreciated.

[image: user properties]

Answer (score 3):

You should use `configureStore` from [`redux-toolkit`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) instead of [`createStore`](https://redux.js.org) if you do not want to add any additional typings

It seems this is what the redux team recommends https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types